# Ruby: Trying to "Update_all" but getting "NameError: uninitialized constant"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

this is the first time I try to write a ruby migration script (I want to update the value of a col for a specific row).

I have a table called "events" with cols "e_id" and "e_text_en". I want to update the "e_text_en" value of the row with ID 6.
In SQL it would be

```
update events set e_text_en = 'blabla' where e_id = 6;
```

My ruby approach: (20141013130000_update_broken_event_texts.rb)

```
class UpdateBrokenTextsEventInEvent < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def Events.up
    Events.where('e_id', 6).update_all(e_text_en: "blablabla")
  end
end
```

But this gives me the error ´NameError: uninitialized constant´

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant UpdateBrokenTextsEventInEvent::Events
/var/.../20141013130000_update_broken_event_texts.rb:2:in `<class:UpdateBrokenTextsEventInEvent>'
/var/.../20141013130000_update_broken_event_texts.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:718:in `load_migration'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:714:in `migration'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:708:in `disable_ddl_transaction'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1012:in `use_transaction?'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:922:in `rescue in block in migrate'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:919:in `block in migrate'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:916:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:916:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in `up'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:742:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

While I searched for a solution I found some advises that tables are called in singular, but even when I try `Event` instead of `Events` I get the same error.

Can anyone help me to correct my ruby?

Versions used:

```
$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.1
$ gem -v
1.8.23.2
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24) [i686-linux] Brightbox
```

edit: Addional infos
Our Schema is created via sql-File. We started to use migrations a short time ago and this is the first update-one. The first two migrations where table-changes. We don't have any ´app/model´ files yet, becuase the other migrations worked without any, e.g.:

```
class AddDeliveriesToEmailQueue < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :email_queue, :deliveries, :int, :null => false, :default => 0, :after => :error
  end
end
```

Comment: Where's `Events ` defined? and why do you need to have `Events.up` anyway in a migration? What's wrong with `self.up`?

Comment: The whole schema is created within an .sql-File cause of Triggers, procedures etc. I tried `self.up` also, giving me similar error `NameError: uninitialized constant UpdateBrokenEventTexts`

Comment: Do you have a model class `Event` inside app/models/event.rb?

Comment: No we dont, see my edit with addional infos.

Comment: Are you planning to have those models later, right?

Comment: Do we need them? (Sry I'm not deep into ruby yet)

Comment: You may need them later when you wanna use these columns in Rails. But, if you don't want them for now then please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem when you create migration and then deside to rename it. Class name in migration should be the same as the filename. You have migration with class `UpdateBrokenTextsEventInEvent` and filename `20141013130000_update_broken_event_texts.rb`, but the class name should be `UpdateBrokenEventTexts`.

Comment: Thank you. You get the accept as SO says you where first (sry Frederick Cheung)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly your migration class name must match the file name (rails will load the migration file and then assume it created a class of the corresponding name). Assuming you don't change your file name, it means that you need to have

```
class UpdateBrokenEventTexts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  ...
end
```

Since you say that you have no model classes, you'll have to use raw SQL, for example

```
class UpdateBrokenEventTexts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    execute "UPDATE events SET e_text_en = 'blablabla'"
  end
end
```

This is pretty much the same as using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` but saves a little on the typing and makes sure Rails understands you're making an irreversible change.

Answer (score 1):

Create `Event` model:

$ rails g model Event

Assuming that you have a model class `Event`(inside *app/models/event.rb*) now, then change these lines:

```
class UpdateBrokenTextsEventInEvent < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def Events.up
    Events.where('e_id', 6).update_all(e_text_en: "blablabla")
  end
end
```

to:

```
class UpdateBrokenTextsEventInEvent < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    Event.where('e_id', 6).update_all(e_text_en: "blablabla")
  end
end
```

Also, I'd recommend you to move such operations in a rake tasks instead of moving them in a migration file:

```
namespace :events do
  desc "Update e_text_en field with blablabla"
  task :update_e_text_en => :environment do
    Event.where('e_id', 6).update_all(e_text_en: "blablabla")
  end
end
```

and then from your terminal:

```
$ rake events:update_e_text_en
```

**UPDATE**: Don't plan to have a model class for now? No worries, you can still update the column but with a SQL query:

```
class UpdateBrokenTextsEventInEvent < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE events SET e_text_en = 'blablabla'")
  end
end
```

Please note that these actions are irreversible(since you don't know what was the previous data in the column you're updating) and that's why they shouldn't be in a migration file. You probably be better with a rake task or something for such operations.

Comment: `up` has to be an instance method, not a class method.

Comment: @Stefan: Actually it is class method. :)

Comment: Even if I copy your SQL-sample, I still get the `NameError: uninitialized constant UpdateBrokenEventTexts` error :( Thanks for the note about irreversible - I have this in mind.